# How to check if a model is empty before changing it?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have an input that needs to use a model, depending on the value of the model.

This is basically what I need:

```
<input v-if"modelOne == ''" v-model="modelOne">
<input v-else               v-model="modelTwo">
```

Except, as I type in the input, `modelOne` is no longer an empty string, so the `v-model` changes to `modelTwo`.

How can I make it only check the value of modelOne when the input is loaded, and not check otherwise?

*Note: this is a simplified version of a dynamic list of inputs. Every input will be using a different model, `row.modelOne` / `row.modelTwo`, and the list of inputs will change.*

Comment: please explain more the note with a scenario

Comment: You're going to get better answers if you describe your problem properly instead of simply.

Comment: Use `v-model.lazy`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `watch` property to have the old and the new value and add a boolean item in your data object as follows :

```
    data(){
         return{ 
            isModelOne:false,
            modelOne:'',
         }
      }
```

watch property  :

```
      watch:{
            modelOne(newval,oldval){
                 oldval==''?this.isModelOne=true:this.isModelOne=false;  
                }
           }
```

template :

```
     <input v-if="isModelOne" v-model="modelOne">
     <input v-else               v-model="modelTwo">
```

Another approach which could be helpful is to use `.lazy` modifier, which will update the bound item after blurring the input:

```js
// ignore the following two lines, they just disable warnings in "Run code snippet"
Vue.config.devtools = false;
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      modelOne: '',
      modelTwo: 'model two'
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.two{
border-radius:20px;
border:2px solid #ff55aa!important;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app" class="container">
  <input v-if= "modelOne == ''" v-model.lazy="modelOne" class="form-control"/>
  
  <input v-else v-model="modelTwo" class="form-control two" />
  <input value="three" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```

Comment: OK, I like the answer, however another dimension to this question (that I didn't disclose because I thought it would be easier) is that this is happening to a dynamic list of inputs. So I wouldn't be able to create a new data object for each input... or could I? I'll update the question to show this.

Comment: @TravisHeeter i updated my answer with some details which could help you